# How to decrease the interval for Horizontal Stacked bar in ChartNew.js?

Tags: chart.js, chartnew.js

I am using ChartNew.js for Horizontal Stacked bar but it appears that it is auto calculating these values. I read the document but did not see any help or options where I could change or fix the issue.
[image]
Because I am not able to change the interval, the text in the first bar is cutting off. Please see the above screenshot.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add some spaces to the end of your y axis labels to push them away from the y axis, like so

```
  "r     ", ...
```

Alternatively, ChartNew allows you to position the y axis on the right side.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I dont think that is an ideal solution. Just adding some spaces wont help. I need Chart to be loaded from X axis only.There has to be something that we can do to increase the interval value. Please advise if you have any other solution in sight. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you post an image showing how it should look like? I'm kind of missing what you mean by `increase the interval value` (assuming you still want to retain the scale). Cheers!

Comment: As per the image above the values (inside red circle), it needs to be displayed inside the blue bar and not outside. Currently I am trying with     inGraphDataAlign: "middle", inGraphDataVAlign: "middle", inGraphDataRotate: 90, to set values inside the blue color bar. Thank you.